# How to use this in this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code in jquery as follows:

```
if($('div').width()>150){

    $('#check').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');  
    $('#check').css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); 

}
```

I am trying to make this code more specific by using 'this' keyword so that the css property would get applied to the particular div only.

**[FIND THE FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/learner420/z3vdk4L1/3/)**

can anyone tell what I am doing wrong, as 'this' keyword is not working in this scenario.

Comment: `this` requires a function that actually sets the value of `this` to something, it can't be used randomly and be expected to magically be what you want it to be.

Comment: Do you realize that `$('div')` returns an _array_ of elements?

Comment: ok, now I got it, but if I want to use the array returned by $('div'), how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the `width` check on all the `div` elements. To do this, you can use `filter` to get the elements where the width meets the requirement, then set the CSS on them:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).width() > 150;
}).css({ 
    'overflow-x': 'scroll',
    'overflow-y': 'hidden'
});
```

Note that it is better practice to apply a class to the elements rather than directly changing CSS, as it allows a better separation of concerns:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).width() > 150;
}).addClass('horizontal-scroll');
```

```css
.horizontal-scroll {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do this

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).width() > 150;
}).css({
    'overflow-x': 'scroll',
    'overflow-y': 'hidden'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3tdw02wv/)

Answer (score 1):

My version with 'this', hope it will help

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).width() > 150) {
       $(this).css('overflow-x', 'scroll');     
       $(this).css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); 
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanyalex/z3vdk4L1/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You should `each` from jquery

```
$.each($('div'),function(){
    if($(this).width()>150){
        $(this).css('overflow-x', 'scroll');     
        $(this).css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="scroll">
    this is going to be a test, in which the text will overflow. 
    this is going to be a test, in which the text will overflow.
    this is going to be a test, in which the text will overflow.
    this is going to be a test, in which the text will overflow.
    this is going to be a test, in which the text will overflow.
</div>

<div class="scroll">
    this is going to be a test, in which the text will not overflow. 
</div>

$(".scroll").each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 150) {
         $(this).css('overflow-x', 'scroll');  
         $(this).css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > 150) {
            $(this).css({
                'overflow-x': 'scroll',
                    'overflow-y': 'hidden'
            });
        }
    });
});
```